# Is it a sin, if any hindu gets married with a person of other religion?

Tags: marriage, other-religions, sin

What do our scriptures say about a person who gets married to a person of another religion?
 Is it considered a sin?

If yes, what is the punishment?

Comment: Bhima married to Hidimba, who was not only of different religion, but entirely a different race. Religion is defined by faith towards particular deity or no deity. Being all inclusive of all faiths, no direct evidence of restrictions on that. Hinduism was only specific to intermarriage among 4 divisions.

Comment: @sv. The possible duplicate does not asks about whether its a sin or not....Its asks about the rules and regulations regarding intermarry....whereas i am asking is it a sin or not?

Answer (score 2):

A person who does not believe in the authority of the Vedas is called a **Nastika** in Hinduism.(as opposed to Astika ,which is the opposite of Nastika)

Now,none of the other religions regard Vedas as their authority.So,from a Hindu's pov,  **followers of other religions are simply Nastikas.**

So,it is sufficient to know how do Hindu Shastras(the Scriptures) treat the **Nastikas.**

> Manu Smriti 11.66.Dhanya Kupya Pasusteyam Madyapa stree Nishevanam Stree Sudra Visa Kshatra Vadho **Nastikyam** Cha Upapatkam-
>
> Stealing grain, base metals, or cattle, intercourse
>   with women who drink spirituous liquor, slaying women, Sudras,
>   Vaisyas, or Kshatriyas, and **atheism**, **(are all) minor offences, causing
>   loss of caste (Upapataka).**
>
> 12.33.Lobha swapno adhritihi Krourya **Nastikyam** Mrittavrittita Yachisnuta Pramadas Cha Tamasm Guna lakshanam
>
> Covetousness, sleepiness, pusillanimity, cruelty, **atheism**, leading
>   an evil life, a habit of soliciting favours, and
>   inattentiveness, are the marks of the quality of Darkness

[image]
[image]

Also note that, although **Nastika** is loosely translated as an **Atheist** by the translator above, but the correct meaning of Nastika in Hinduism is as given at the beginning only.That's why i also gave the transliterated Sanskrit verses  so as to avoid any confusions of that nature.

So,as one can see, being a Nastika is condemned in Scriptures as being a minor sin.So,marrying a nastika will be condemnable act for any Hindu without doubt.

And,in any case,the Scriptures also clearly say that,any doctrines,philosophies (or even religions) that are not based on the Vedas are false .So,obviously followers of such religions are to be avoided.

> Manu 12.95. All those traditions (smriti) and those despicable systems
>   of philosophy, which are not based on the Veda, produce no reward
>   after death; for they are declared to be founded on Darkness.
>
> 12.96. All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda), which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false, because they are of
>   modern date.

[image]

My conclusion-Although we can not find any **direct references** of other religions in Hindu Shastras as such,but still that **a Hindu marrying a non-hindu is condemnable act** is made quite clear from the passages above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, how does it matter if someone marries one who doesn't believe in Vedas? By the way, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Actually there was no way i cud have answered this Q directly from Scriptures..Simply becoz the scriptures won't tell us how to deal with followers of other religions as we know them today..They will at most tell us how shud one treat those who contempt Gods,those who do Veda ninda,those who disregard scriptures and those who don't believe in the authority of Vedas..And followers of the other religions will fall in atleast one if not more of the categories mentioned before..In any case Scriptures will not approve such marriages..

Comment: For example they r quite clear on the fact that beliefs and philosophies that are created without the support of the Vedas r false and worthless..So,needless to say about what the stand of scriptures' will be on followers of such belief systems.. as for ur Q-- Those who do not believe in Vedas are called nastika ,so scriptures will not praise such marriages without doubt..& as for the downvote i did not mind..i know who voted down actually...